# Vaadin 23.1.6 ComboBox : Clear combo does not work anymore after CustomValueSetEvent

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I want to use the ComboBox component and its feature **addCustomValueSetListener**. Here is the code I use.

```
@Route(value="temp", layout = MainLayout::class)
class TempPage: VerticalLayout() {

    init {
        val combo = ComboBox<String>()
        combo.setItems(listOf()) // I get the same behavior with a real list of items

        combo.addCustomValueSetListener {
            add(Span(it.detail)) // Use the new value
            it.source.clear() // Clear the ComboBox to let the user add another custom value
        }

        add(combo)
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I press Enter after typing a custom value, the combobox is not cleared. In fact, it is cleared but only the first time, afterwards, the clear() method does not work anymore.

Am I missing something ? *(I am coding in kotlin, not in java, I don't know if the problem can come from that)*

UPDATE:

It seems the [problem is known](https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/1090) and should be fixed, but I still have the problem

Answer (score 0):

This problem is still not fixed. I've commented on the issue.

If your ComboBox contains String then you can set "" as the value:

```
combo.setValue("");
```

But for other objects it seems that setValue(null) only works the first time as you described and you have to use the ugly workaround.